Is there unit of time/space in synthetic differential geometry model in physics?
In synthetic differential geometry we deal with infinitesimals $\varepsilon$ that don't have quantities.
It's possible to apply SDG model in physics.
Simple example is function of time $f(t)=t^2$ where $f(t)$ is coordinate of moving particle.
If we apply SDG we can get coordinate $f(\varepsilon)$ at time $\varepsilon$. But is it possible to say that time was $\varepsilon$ seconds?
My question: is there unit of time/space (as I mentioned above - seconds) in synthetic differential geometry model in physics?
Thanks.
